# Why is the Entity Framework inserting when it should update?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I use the following RIA Services call to register and return a `Project` entity.

```
// On Server; inside RIA Domain Service
[Invoke]
public Project CreateNewProject(String a_strKioskNumber)
{
  Decimal dProjectID = ObjectContext.RegisterProjectNumber(a_strKioskNumber)
                       .FirstOrDefault() ?? -1m;

  // Tried this but it returned zero (0)
  //int nChanged = ObjectContext.SaveChanges();

  var project = (from qProject in ObjectContext.Projects.Include("ProjectItems")
                 where qProject.ID == dProjectID
                 select qProject)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

  if (project == null)
    return null;

  return project;
}
```

As you can see, it calls a stored procedure that returns a project ID. It uses this ID to look up the `Project` entity itself and return it.  When the `Project` entity is returned to the client it is detached.  I attach it to the `DomainContext` and modify it.

```
// At Client
_activeProject = a_invokeOperation.Value; // <-- Detached
_context.Projects.Attach(_activeProject); // <-- Unmodified

if (_activeProject != null)
{
  _activeProject.AuthenticationType = "strong"; // <-- Modified
  _activeProject.OwnerID = customer.ID;
  _projectItems.Do(pi => _activeProject.ProjectItems.Add(pi));
  _activeProject.Status = "calculationrequired";
}
```

At this point it has an entity state of `Modified`.  When I submit changes it gives me an exception regarding a UNIQUE KEY violation as if it is trying to insert it rather than update it.

```
// At Client
_context.SubmitChanges(OnProjectSaved, a_callback);
```

I'm using the same `DomainContext` instance for all operations.  Why should this not work?
What's going wrong? This is rather frustrating.

**Edits:**

I tried this (as suggested by Jeff):

```
[Invoke]
public void SaveProject(Project a_project)
{
  var project = (from qProject in ObjectContext.Projects
                 where qProject.ID == a_project.ID
                 select qProject)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

  project.SubmitDate = a_project.SubmitDate;
  project.PurchaseDate = a_project.PurchaseDate;
  project.MachineDate = a_project.MachineDate;
  project.Status = a_project.Status;
  project.AuthenticationType = a_project.AuthenticationType;
  project.OwnerID = a_project.OwnerID;
  project.ProjectName = a_project.ProjectName;
  project.OwnerEmail = a_project.OwnerEmail;
  project.PricePerPart = a_project.PricePerPart;
  project.SheetQuantity = a_project.SheetQuantity;
  project.EdgeLength = a_project.EdgeLength;
  project.Price = a_project.Price;
  project.ShipToStoreID = a_project.ShipToStoreID;
  project.MachiningTime = a_project.MachiningTime;

  int nChangedItems = ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

It did absolutely nothing.  It didn't save the project.

Comment: "When I submit changes it gives me an exception"

Comment: Are you sure the UNIQUE KEY violation is being caused by the Project entity?  What about the project items you are adding to the active project, where are they coming from?  I assume the error message tells you exactly what is causing it, but I just thought I would verify to be sure.

Comment: Did you verify that the changes you made on the client were included in the server call?  If they were, then I don't know why it did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you add a SaveProject method on the server side and send the object back to the server for saving?

I've not done EF with RIA Services, but I've always sent my objects back to the server for saving.  I'm assuming that SubmitChanges call you are making wires up everything properly for you for sending it back to the server, but perhaps it is doing something wrong and handling it manually will fix it.

Comment: Possibly.  You mean like an Invoke?  I'll have to try that.

Comment: For some reason, it forces me to have an Update method (that does nothing) just to be able to edit the `Project`. I think if I played with it long enough it would work, but I've decided that a simpler and cleaner solution would be to use DTO's. That is, a separate object type that is used exclusively on the client side. That way it gives me more control over updating and initializing. Ultimately because I have to do it all manually. I've been fighting this method because I wanted everything to be more "seamless" Why does MS make everything so complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the source at the moment but I have seen it recommended that you use a new context for each operation in Silverlight. I ran into a similar problem today and it was because I was using a Service level context that was remembering previous values that I didnt want, I changed to creating a new context for each service call and the behavior became what I expected.

```
public void SaveResponses(ICollection<Responses> items, Action<SubmitOperation> callback)
        {
            try
            {
                SurveysDomainContext _context = new SurveysDomainContext();
                foreach (Responses item in items)
                {
                    _context.Responses.Add(item);
                }

                _context.SubmitChanges(callback, null);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: but this IS a single operation.  Its all happening at once.

Comment: but you appear to be using a global DataContext. You should try using a new instance.

Comment: yeah, but then all of my state held objects become detached (and thus useless). I've seen it said that you should do this, but I don't believe it. If RIA Services cannot maintain state, its useless.  Its no longer an ORM layer; it becomes a really, really, complicated query engine. Useless.

Comment: RIA Services isn't the ORM. Entity framework is the ORM. Ria Services is alot simpler than trying to work the same process in WPF. That is one of the reasons I moved to Silverlight from WPF...

Comment: I know, I know. I've learned that since.  Its an extension of the ORM across a network.  Its a fancy version of WCF.  I prefer WCF itself now.  More flexible and fewer unexplained exceptions.  I'm a programmer, darn it, not a bloody miracle worker!

Comment: heh..im just the opposite. I prefer Ria for the time being.. :)

Comment: I would prefer RIA, if it gave me more control.  It is very restrictive, though it does have a lot of advantages.

Answer (score 1):

As for the notion that one can't use a singleton global DomainContext, this is actually debatable.  In my project I use a singleton DomainContext with no issues.  In other projects, we have created a new DomainContext for different modules in the app where the entities are reused. There are definitely pros and cons.  See:
[Strategies for Handling Your DomainContext (external blog)](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-WCF-RIA-Services-strategies-for-handling-your-Domain-Context-part-one.aspx)

Comment: Yes! I believe a DomainContext should survive a use case scenario. When its no longer needed or in-between use cases, you release it and start a new one.  That's what I do with my applications.  I keep them in global places (such as inside a singleton instance) because the use case spans multiple navigational pages. It doesn't mean its static and application wide.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that when you attach your project to the DomainContext it checks the _context.Projects entityset and isn't finding an entity with that primary key, and then assumes that the newly attached entity doesn't exist serverside yet and that submitting changes should insert it.  A possible workaround might be to explicitly load the newly created Project into the DomainContext.  It would ensure that it sets the correct state on the entity--that is, that the project already exists on the server and that that it's an update instance, rather than an insert instance.

So maybe something like:

```
//after your Project has already been created serverside with the invoke
_context.Load(_context.SomeQueryThatLoadsYourNewlyCreatedProject(), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, (LoadOperation lo) => {
    Project project = lo.Entities.FirstOrDefault(); //is attached and has correct state
    if (project != null)
    {
        project.AuthenticationType = "strong";
        project.OwnerID = customer.ID;
        project.Do(pi => _activeProject.ProjectItems.Add(pi));
        project.Status = "calculationrequired";
        _context.SubmitChanges(); //hopefully will trigger an update, rather than an insert
    } 
});
```

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't help.  It still tries to create a new Project when I update the one I create.